# Maintain single CSS perspective-origin for entire page

Tags: css

Is there a way to set perspective-origin to a single point for an entire page?

When the docs say perspectives for child elements, they apparently mean direct child elements only.

So if we want a page full of transformed elements to have the same perspective, we either have to have all those elements as direct children of one element, or do some manual math for every element to match up the origin - and the origin is relative to the elements bounds. That's impractical if you have moving, interactive elements, I really hope I'm just wrong about something. In my head this should work exactly like position.

```css
.main{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: left bottom;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.plane1{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
.plane2{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="plane1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="plane2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: add perspective to the body element? everything is child of body

Comment: @TemaniAfif read again - only **direct children** are affected, per the demo code above.

Comment: because you have to also consider `transform-style: preserve-3d;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

Comment: @TemaniAfif example? `transform-style` keeps things in the same 3d space, so it would be nice if it affected this, but as far as I can tell it does not affect perspective-origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temani Afif's answer in the thread is correct - `transform-style: preserve-3d` must be set for every descendant between the perspective declaration and the element to be subjected to that perspective. As the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) states:

> 'As this property is not inherited, it must be set for all non-leaf
> descendants of the element.'

```css
html, body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: left;
}

.main {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  height: 500px;
}

* {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.plane1{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
.plane2{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  transform: rotateX(5deg) rotateY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="plane1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="plane2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```